# How to enable text after adding a new filed in a Form with Report?

Tags: oracle-apex, oracle-apex-5

I have designed a "Form on a table with Report".

[image]

I edited a form and added a new field - "Subject". Whenever I updated that field it is not getting reflected in the report.

[image]

How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit Added Page Item go to >> Source and set type : Database Column

Database Column : (Name Of Table column you want to Update). Now you entered information stored in table.

Comment: Thanks Pars:) Really helpful:):)